# change title in browser history after a page is loaded

Tags: javascript

This would show up as "a" in chrome://history/. I'm asking for a way to change the title in history when doing some AJAX after page is loaded.

a.html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
        <head>
            <meta charset="utf-8">
            <title>a</title>
        </head>
        <body>
            <script src="a.js" async></script>
        </body>
</html>
```

a.js:

```
document.title="abv";
```

Comment: that's up to the browser. you can't control that.

Comment: You can change it in the `success` handler of ajax http://output.jsbin.com/yegecutalu